# AngularJS backspace keypress

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, keypress

I need to capture user's backspaces inside an input.

So I've done this:

```
<input type="text" ui-keypress="{8:'removeTagOnBackspace()'}" ng-model="searchStudent" />
```

And then, inside my controller I've done this, just to check if it's working:

```
$scope.removeTagOnBackspace = function() {
    console.log('here');
};
```

But is not printing anything.
What is wrong with this? Is angular able to capture backspaces?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Got it!

```
<input type="text" ng-keydown="removeTagOnBackspace($event)" />
```

And:

```
$scope.removeTagOnBackspace = function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 8) {
        console.log('here!');
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this was interesting to run into - ng-keypress doesn't capture backspace key events (but does work for other keys), but ng-keydown works for the backspace key just fine.

Comment: @mahesh Works with IE10

Comment: Ended up using `ng-keyup` because when `keydown` was called the input was not yet updated.